# Finding a ortogonal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=PDP^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

So we are given a practice exam for our linear algebra exam. The problem is, given a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&0&1\\0&4&0\\1&0&3\end{pmatrix}$ I had to check if $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is a eigenvector associated with matrix $A$, which indeed it is as $A\bf v=\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\\4\end{pmatrix}=4\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ hence the eigenvector is for eigenvalue $\lambda = 4$. I want to find a orthogonal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=PDP^T$ for the diagonal matrix, it consists of the eigenvalues in the main diagonal, as for the orthogonal matrix $P$, I went with the following. $$\text{Nul}\left(\lambda I-A\right)=\bf 0$$ which gave me that $\bf x=\begin{pmatrix}s\\t\\s\end{pmatrix}=s\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ that means that two of the eigenvalues is equals to eachother, in otherwords $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=4$ (is it possible to find the other corresponding eigenvalue without computing it using the charateristic polynomial?) as this will save me time). So I let $S=\text{Span}\left\{\bf{v}_1,\bf{v}_2\right\}$ and used G-S process to find an orthonormal basis for the eigenspace letting $\bf{x}_1=\bf{u}_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ I found that $\bf{x}_2=\bf{u}_2$ as $\bf{u}_2\cdot \bf{x_1}=0$ hence $\bf{x}_2=u_2$ I also needed the last eigenvector which is $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ which gave me that the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0&1&0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$$ but as I took $PDP^T$ I got $$\begin{pmatrix}3&0&-1\\0&4&0\\-1&0&3\end{pmatrix}\neq A$$ I don't see what I did wrong here.

Comment: Your result matrix should be diagonal. You forgot to write the results of $Av_i$ for your basis vectors $v_i$ in the same basis $v_i$.

Comment: I don't quite get it, could you rephrase it? sorry

Comment: I did the same as you and get the correct result. Your procedure is fine, I guess you made a mistake when multiply the matrices and/or take the transpose of $P$.

Comment: ahhh i see my error now, I got it now Berci, I didn't order the eigenvectors and eigenvalues correctly, I used the diagonal matrix $2,4,4$ in the main diagonal instead of $4,4,2$ now I get the correct output.... i'm sorry

Comment: To be honest, for first I thought that the matrix in the middle was your result for $D$, but it was not diagonal. But that stood rather for $P$, sorry for the confusion..